# Nginx reverse proxy not working with a different port number

Tags: nginx

I have this very simple nginx.conf file.If I go to `serverip:80` or `serverip` in my browser, I get the index.html page located at `/var/www/html`. That works. However, if I go to `serverip:7654`, I expect to be shown the site running on `localhost:7777` on my server, but instead I just get a timeout and 404. If I SSH to my server and do `curl localhost:7777`, I get the desired response. See the below config file:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type  text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type application/x-javascript;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 7654;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7777/;
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type  text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type application/x-javascript;
        }
    }
}
```

The strangest thing is, if I do this instead:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location /mysite/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7777/;
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type  text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type application/x-javascript;
        }
    }
}
```

Going to `serverip:80/mysite` or `serverip/mysite` works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to `localhost:7654` from SSH console? What are your `iptables` settings? Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: Missing UFW setting confirmed! I wrongly assumed `ufw allow 'Nginx Full'` covered this as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. Yesterday you asked a question about conditional routing based of `referer` header. I've managed to develop a solution, but you deleted your question before I wrote an answer. Do you decide to do it some other way?

Comment: Hi @IvanShatsky , I figured I must have either mistyped my question, or was doing something that nginx was not really intended for. So I was looking at a different solution direction. I'm sorry if I caused you confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I used UFW with `ufw allow 'Nginx Full'` for port 80, but needed a seperate rule for port 7654.